# How to import custom font for the svg's text element in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, svg

I am on a webserver using NextJs, codesandbox.io and stackblitz.com prevent me from download font on their cloud interface AFAIK. I have created a Github repo so you can test the code yourself on local. Here the link: https://github.com/Hocoh/svg_font_firefox/blob/master/README.md

I would import a custom font to use in Firefox for a SVG's text element that I am using as a clip-path to animate panel over it for a *discover text effect*. For the sake of simplicity I have integrated only one panel in my example tough there is five panels in the real example. The current rendering fails to implement the custom font in my page. 
To import my customFont, I have tried to:

- use a style block nested in the SVG's element,
- use the font-family attribute in the text and text span,
- use inline-style,
- play with CSS' selector, even using the wildcare with CSS with the !important attribute

none of them work, in Firefox my font displayed is the raw font. I fail to find an consistent documentation about the importation of custom font for the SVG element too. *If I have understood well, Firefox follow a strict implementation of the SVG specs and that can explain why my code works well in Google Chrome and Opera for example -above strict compliance, just plain and usual CSS with selector- and would fail in Firefox.*

How can I display my custom font on the SVG text's element?

Here my ReactJS' snippet:

import React from "react";

export default () => (

```
 <svg 

    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    width="100%" height="100%"
    // viewBox="50% 50% 20% 20%"
>

    {/* define style in SVG scope */} 
    <defs>
        {/* work when importing external  stylesheet
             <style type="text/css"> 
                {` 
                   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap');
                `}
            </style>
        */}

        {/* fail on local font's importing*/}

        {/* fail using relative path
            <style type="text/css"> 
                {` 
                    @font-face{
                        font-family:AnuDaw;
                        src:
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.ttf") format("truetype"),
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.woff") format("woff"),
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.woff2") format("woff2"),
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.eot"),
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
                            url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.svg")  format('svg');
                    }
                    text{
                        font-family: AnuDaw;
                        font-size:3em;
                    }
                `}
            </style>
        */}

        {/* fail using root path*/}
         <style type="text/css"> 
            {` 
                @font-face{
                    font-family:AnuDaw;
                    src:
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.ttf") format("truetype"),
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.woff") format("woff"),
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.woff2") format("woff2"),
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.eot"),
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
                        url("../font/Anud/AnuDaw.svg")  format('svg');
                }
                text{
                    font-family: AnuDaw;
                    font-size:3em;
                }
            `}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <defs> 
        <g  
            className="text_group"        
            id="panel_animation"
           // style={{fontFamily:"AnuDaw"}}
            y="0"

        >
             <text   
                    wordSpacing="-.45em"    
                    fontFamily="AnuDaw"
                >
                <tspan  x="0%" y="0%"  
                    dy="1.6em"   
                    >So</tspan> 
                <tspan  x="0%" y="-5%" 
                    dy="3em"  
                    fontFamily="AnuDaw">Food</tspan>
                </text> 

        </g>
    </defs> 

    <use
        width="100%" height="100%" 
        x="50%"
        xlinkHref="#panel_animation"                      
    /> 
</svg>    
  )
```

Comment: You are displaying this via a web server and not just as a file on a filesystem aren't you? That's not a react snippet, it's just an SVG file.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for your answer, yes I am on a webserver using NextJs, codesandbox.io and stackblitz.com prevent me from download font on their cloud interface AFAIK. I have created a Github repo so you can test the code yourself on local. Here the link: https://github.com/Hocoh/svg_font_firefox/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is this inline SVG? Did you try to add style tag inside html?

Comment: @jcubic thanks for your comment, yes I think it is inline SVG and yes I have tried to add style tag in the SVG's text elements, you check that in the repo I have provided, all the code is here,

Comment: I mean add to html not in SVG, use in head of the html file but use selector `svg text`

Comment: I see it's react use `<><style>svg text { font-family: xxx }</style><svg>...</svg><>` you can also add some random id or class so the style will be used only for your svg (so it don't leak). It can be just name of your component and index from global counter increased in constructor.

Comment: @jcubic hanks for the hint, always good to know for future case :). Currently I think I have paid attention to theses parts, cause it works in other browsers, I assume if it was a pure CSS' leaking it would break in more browser than just Firefox. Also the answer of Peter T Bosse II helped me to solve my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your Github repo](https://github.com/Hocoh/svg_font_firefox), I believe the issue is due to Next.js not serving your "font" directory. Static assets need to be served from a directory named "static", "public", or "src/public" directory (the last two [require Next.js 9.1 or later](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-1#public-directory-support)).

I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/Hocoh/svg_font_firefox/pull/1) which seems to solve the issue you've described, at least in my testing. If it does not solve your problem, feel free to reach out and I'd be happy to help further.

Comment: seems it works on my computer too, I will play a bit with that, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Also I would add to the answer of Peter T Bosse II that in my case the *True Type Font*'s version of the font just didn't work with Firefox but worked with the other browsers, so I had to manage the font's *extension* choice so it works also in Firefox.

Currently I don't know why the *True Type Font*'s version of the font didn't works in Firefox. Maybe if I recompiled it the *True Type Font*'s version of the font would now works with Firefox too.

Meanwhile, I have simply placed the *WOFF* and *WOFF2*'s version of the font at the top of my @font-face import -the import seems to stop at the first file met probably for performance optimization, so it didn't test the browser' compatibility with other fonts.

Now that I have placed the *WOFF* and *WOFF2*'s version of the font at the top of my @font-face import it works well on Firefox too.

The browser use the *WOFF*'s file -meaning, the WOFF1 standard's version of WOFF extension-, that is placed at top of the @font-face import and hence is the first loaded font according to my devconsole network's feebacks.